# How to evaluate e^x in a numerically stable way?

Tags: r, precision, scientific-computing, numerical-stability

**Background:** I am simulating data from a [Cox proportional hazards model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model). There is a method provided by Bender et. al (2005). It is explained and implemented in R very well in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135129/162482). The intricacies of Cox models are not important to this question.

**Problem:** I need to evaluate exp(-1 * X * beta). Due to some of the specifics of the problem I'm working on, either X or beta needs to be relatively large, somewhere between 50 and 100. I believe this causes accuracy problems.

```
X.stable = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by  = .1)
beta = 1
exp(-1 * X.stable * beta)
```

> 1.0000000 0.9048374 0.8187308 0.7408182 0.6703200 0.6065307 0.5488116 0.4965853 0.4493290 0.4065697 0.3678794

```
X.unstable = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by  = 5)
exp(-1 * X.unstable * beta)
```

> 1.000000e+00 6.737947e-03 4.539993e-05 3.059023e-07 2.061154e-09 1.388794e-11 9.357623e-14 6.305117e-16
>    [9] 4.248354e-18 2.862519e-20 1.928750e-22 1.299581e-24 8.756511e-27 5.900091e-29 3.975450e-31 2.678637e-33
>   [17] 1.804851e-35 1.216099e-37 8.194013e-40 5.521082e-42 3.720076e-44

I don't believe that the values at the end are correct. Did R really calculate exp(x) to 44 digits? Eventually, I plug these values in a function, and I think I'm getting nonsense answers. Am I putting to little faith in R or am I correct. If this is in fact a problem, is there anything I can do about it?

I have considered using only the first 2-3 terms of the Taylor series representation of e^x. I could do that without a problem. I do not know if that will solve my issues though, because I assume R is doing something like that under the hood anways,

To boil down my question,can I get precise values from the exp() function, even if the arguments are large?

Comment: 1. try taking `log(exp(-100))`   2. When R says `exp(-100) = 3.720076e-44` it is not computing to 44 decimal places.  It is computing the mantissa to 16 decimal places and the exponent to 2 decimal places. Think about multiplying 1 e-100 times 1 e-100.  You don't have to do 200 digit calculations. You multiply 1 times 1 and add the exponents.

Comment: Be very carefull with what seems to be *stable*. `X.stable[4] - 0.3` gives `[1] 5.551115e-17`. See [R FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html) or [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).